# Quirky animation on SurfaceView with good FPS

Tags: android, animation, canvas, surfaceview

I implement linear animation for lot of objects on `SurfaceView` and found the following issue: on `Samsung S4` and S3 the animation is quirky, but FPS is near 60. On other devices works perfectly.

After I disabled hardware acceleration in Manifest it worked much better, but sometimes the screen is flickering.
Please advice where might be the root of problem. Thanks!

upd: as for code - I don't create any objects in realtime but reusing the ones from object pools.

Comment: If you're drawing on a SurfaceView surface with a Canvas, hardware acceleration is never employed.  You need to include more details about what it is you're doing and the nature of the flickering.  The performance of software rendering is affected by the size of the surface (which, if you haven't modified it, is proportional to the pixel size of the display) and the performance characteristics of the CPU.

Comment: @fadden yep, I read about that acceleration is not applied for SurfaceView, but the strange thing is that the animation becomes _much_ smoother on Samsung S4/S3 if I set hardwareaccelerated to false into manifest.